# Search with Levenshetein algorithm using more keywords

Tags: mysql, search, group-by, having

i'm trying to write a simple search engine, these are my tables:

```
wordlist
-----------------
id   |   word
 1   |   telecamera
 2   |   outside

wordoccurrence
---------------------------------------
id   |   wordlist_id |  product_id
 1   |      1        |      1
 2   |      1        |      2
 3   |      2        |      1
 4   |      2        |      2


product
---------------------------------------
  id   |  description             | type
   1   |   telecamera outside     |   1
   2   |   telecamera outside     |   2
```

Now, this is my poor query:

```
SELECT p.* , levenshtein(w.word,  "telecamera") AS score_1, 
levenshtein(w2.word,  "outside") AS score_2, 
w.word as myword, w2.word as myword2
FROM product p, wordlist w, wordlist w2, wordoccurrence o
WHERE (o.wordlist_id = w.id or o.wordlist_id = w2.id) and w.word != w2.word
GROUP BY score_1, score_2, p.id
HAVING score_1 <6 AND score_2 < 6
```

For now, don't consider levenshtein about the length of the terms. (6 is an example)

I'd like to have 2 rows (because there are two different types) as result if user searches "telecamera outside".

I want an AND, not a OR for search terms.

Thank you a lot.

Alberto

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Hello Strawberry, i've problems with SQLfiddle: Schema Creation Failed: Can't create table 'db_2_ad467.#sql-665d_22901' (errno: 150).  I'd like to get products using two keywords and levenshtein. Even a query example can be useful

Comment: OK... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68e52

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9f16b Now there's the schema, but levenshtein function is impossibile to add! wordlist and wordoccurrence are related to the product table. I'd like to show products based on the two terms above.

Comment: Let's leave that bit out for now. Go for something a little more generic - this is surely not the kind of problem for which one would normally require Levenshtein!

Comment: Replace levenshtein(w.word,  "telecamera") with RAND() is equal...For me it's that kind of problem.

Comment: OK. Now re-read my first comment.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53b531/7

Now i have a lot of records with id=1 and id=2, but i want only two records with id=1 and id=2 and both score_1 and score_2 between my values.

If you need something else, i'm here. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: I guess I'd just like to see the desired result set

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int, `score_1` int, `score_2` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `score_1`, `score_2`)
VALUES
(1, 0.000568, 0.043426),
(2, 0.000983, 0.179062)
;
```

This is the desired result set.
I'd like to have also the result set where there are the minimum score_1 and score_2.

I hope you meant this Strawberry. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Delete this, and amend your question accordingly - but I still don't understand why you want a score at all!?!?!? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to get proper rows based on search words (without like and fulltext searches) with levenshtein, so i want the best results using score_1 and score_2 (ASC) which are the return values of the levenshtein function for the two keywords. One table lists the occurrences for each product and a table lists all the keywords for each product. Thanks a lot Strawberry.